# Need to add a journal title and logo to the following template

Tags: titles, journal-publishing, frame-title, logos, journal

[image]  I need to add a journal title on the top left and logo on the top right, of the first page.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{cases}
%\usepackage[initials]{amsrefs}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\textwidth=35truepc
\textheight=45truepc

\paperheight=260mm
\paperwidth=240mm



\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}


\title[]{}


\author[]{}
\address[]{}
\email{{}}
\keywords{}
\subjclass[2010]{}

%\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}
\end{abstract}

\maketitle 

\end{document}
```

Thanks a alot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `amsart` class provides a hook to adjust to your needs. You can put the Journal name and logo in there.

[image: result]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{cases}
%\usepackage[initials]{amsrefs}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\textwidth=35truepc
\textheight=45truepc

\paperheight=260mm
\paperwidth=240mm



\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\makeatletter
\newlength{\logoheight}
\setlength{\logoheight}{40pt} % set your logo height
\renewcommand{\@maketitle@hook}{% the hook provided, all below is put before the title
    \parbox[c]{.5\linewidth}{Journal name\\Volume\dots}% used parbox to have multiple lines available
    \hfill% to put the logo on the right
    \raisebox{\dimexpr-.5\logoheight+.5ex\relax}% This aligns the logo vertically 
    {\includegraphics[height=\logoheight]{example-image-1x1}}\par% your logo
    \vspace{15pt}% Space between logo and Title
}
\makeatother


\title[]{The Magnificent Title}


\author[]{}
\address[]{}
\email{{}}
\keywords{}
\subjclass[2010]{}

%\date{\today}

\begin{document}

    \begin{abstract}
        This is the abstract.
    \end{abstract}

    \maketitle 

\end{document}
```